# Merging different .woff2 files into one

Tags: webfonts, google-fonts, woff, woff2

I downloaded a font via google fonts. That file comes in different styles(?), e.g.: black, italic, bold, etc. and each is a separate `.ttf` file:

```
Merriweather-BoldItalic.tff
Merriweather-LightItalic.tff
...
```

In order to use it as a webfont, i converted the files individually into `.woff2` files using the [`woff2_compress`](https://github.com/google/woff2) command line tool. That also works and I got:

```
Merriweather-BoldItalic.woff2
Merriweather-LightItalic.woff2
...
```

Now I wonder: is it possible to merge all these `.woff2` files into one, maintaining the style info for each file? If yes: which command line tool can I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [variable fonts.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Fonts/Variable_Fonts_Guide)
They include different design axis which could be interpolated to get e.g. different font-weights or font-widths.

More and more google webfonts are also available as variable fonts.
In your case the sans serif sibling ["Merriweather Sans"](https://fonts.google.com/?query=merriweather&vfonly=true) is already available.  The serif version can currently only be used as a traditional font.

There's also a filter option on google fonts to show only variable fonts.

[image: google fonts options: show only variable fonts]

Traditional "static" fonts can't be merged into one file since they **can't contain multiple font-styles**.
Technically, you could create a variable font yourself, but that's a pretty advanced task.

There is also the [TrueType Collection (TTC) format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType#TrueType_Collection). But afaik: it's not supported by most browsers.

BTW. if you need local woff2 copies of your fonts you can also use [google webfont helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts). This way you get the official woff2 versions - which might be more reliable than than self compiled font files.